# Layout of a LiFePo battery pack with serial and parallel cells

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-charge-controller, lifepo4

Due to space I need to build a LiFePo battery pack with 8 individual cells.
Each individual cell has 12V and 50 Ah, and the pack has to have 24V and 200 Ah. This would be the specific cell I plan on using: [ECO-WORTHY LiFePO4 Battery 12 V 50 Ah](https://www.amazon.de/ECO-WORTHY-Temperature-Protection-3000-15000-Motorhome/dp/B0C9PZB6QR/ref=mp_s_a_1_9?crid=1UWEZ5RNWSK0U&keywords=100Ah%2B12V%2BLithium%2BBatterie%2BLiFePO4%2BAkku%2BBMS&psr=EY17&qid=1700502268&s=black-friday&sprefix=100ah%2B12v%2Blithium%2Bbatterie%2Blifepo4%2Bakku%2Bbms%2Caps%2C248&sr=1-9&th=1&psc=1)

Basically, I think of a connection with 4 packs in parallel, each with 2 cells in series.

I have read many articles, but couldn't find a unified opinion, if:

1. This is possible to due balancing issues?
2. How to properly setup the serial-parallel layout?
3. How the charging of the system/individual cells should be done?

Regarding point 1) and 2) most manufactures say max 4 cells could be used together.
For example this link says more can be used together: [How to connect batteries in series and parallel](https://www.power-sonic.com/blog/how-to-connect-batteries-in-series-and-parallel/#:%7E:text=When%20connecting%20batteries%20in%20parallel,positive%20terminal%20of%20the%20next.)

Regarding point 3) I am completely confused, and I understand it depends on the layout.
This battery pack will be part of a larger system with two 200 W solar panels and a charge controller such this one: [Victron Energy SmartSolar MPPT 75V 15 Amp 12/24 Volt Solar Charge Controller](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/SmartSolar-MPPT-15-Controller-Bluetooth/dp/B075NQQRPD/ref=pd_aw_day0fbt_img_m_sccl_1/262-8299873-0481756?pd_rd_w=zi9pM&content-id=amzn1.sym.77abd94d-570c-47ab-864d-15f23aaa3451&pf_rd_p=77abd94d-570c-47ab-864d-15f23aaa3451&pf_rd_r=BNEYVRX0S4T3GZ6XZSFT&pd_rd_wg=JDYyK&pd_rd_r=a1eafa4c-546c-4527-bb6c-b487af8e5458&pd_rd_i=B075NQQRPD&psc=1)